# How can $e^{i\pi}+1$ be zero?

Tags: complex-numbers, irrational-numbers

So, most of us are familliar with Euler’s equation stating that $e^{i\pi}+1=0$. But I was wondering: how can an irrational number to the power of another irrational number equal a whole integer? And if that works, then how can $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ if $i$ isn’t even real?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341214/proof-that-ei-pi-1/341228

Comment: Check out my blog article on the subject: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php

Comment: To can appreciate deeply at all this equation you need to study trigonometry, complex numbers and Taylor's series.

Comment: Why shouldn't an irrational power of an irrational number be an integer? And why shouldn't $e^{i\pi} + 1$ be real even though $i$ is purely imaginary? Please clarify what you don't understand about these facts?

Comment: Darn. I’ve studied none of those except complex numbers, but just a bit.

Comment: @Detmondyou Then you will appreciate better that formula in the future!

Comment: You should also get a kick out of: $e^{i} = i^{2/\pi}$  A real number raised to an imaginary value which equals an imaginary value raised to a real power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can an irrational number to the power of another irrational number
>   equal a whole integer?

You mean like $e^{\ln 2}=2$? Mind you, that's still a positive integer, unlike $-1$.

> And if that works, then how can $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ if isn’t even real?

Well, $i$ is the reason the exponential doesn't have to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to [Euler's identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2660361/505767)

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta\implies e^{i\pi}=\cos \pi + i \sin \pi=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^{i\pi}$ = $\cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)$ and $\sin(\pi) = 1$, $\cos(\pi) = -1$ you get

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1 = 0
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Taking a slightly different approach to the other answers, because I think your confusion is elsewhere. You asked

> How can an irrational number to the power of another irrational number equal a whole integer?

But this is entirely possible, even for real numbers. For instance, both $a = \sqrt{10}$ and $b = \log_{10} 4$ are irrational, but $a^b = 
\sqrt{10}^{\log_{10} 4}=\sqrt{10}^{2 \log_{10} 2} = 10^{\log_{10}2} = 2$, which is an integer.

Comment: Yes, but you forget, $10^x$ counters $log_{10}n$. That’s like if I used the example $\sqrt{2}^2$

Comment: That's exactly the point, and $e^{i x}$ counters $\pi$ in the same way.

Comment: Oh, ok. (Also realized this equation uses radians instead of degrees...)